# __ptr32 to pin_ptr gives compilation error on x64 configuration

Tags: c++-cli, 32bit-64bit

I am wrapping a method of dll(c++) in C++/CLI. I am using x86 windows-xp machine with Vc++ 2010.

I have both x86 and x64 configuration in my c++/CLI project.

I am getting a compile error in x64 only. here is code snippet

```
struct A
{
    int data;
    A *__ptr32 next;
}

pin_ptr<A *>pinned = &obj->next; // A obj
```

above line is being compiled only in x86 configuration.
In x64 im am getting a compile error: `can't convert A * to pin_ptr <Type>`

compiler option: /clr

Comment: Why do you use 32-bit pointers on a 64-bit platform?

Comment: Lots of things don't make sense about this code.  Starting with pinning something that is obviously not a managed object reference.  So get rid of that first, then start thinking about how you are going get that A* updated to __ptr64.

Answer (score 1):

__pt32 constrains the pointer to a 32 bit pointer that only works on x86.

x64 works with 64 bit pointers...

just remove the size constraint and use it like a regular pointer:

```
 struct A
  {
   int data;
   A* next;
  }
```

Comment: I have dll in which A is defined as mentioned. So I need to rebuild that dll. Is this the only way ?

Comment: x64 architecture uses 64 bit pointers. A 32 bit pointer is invalid because it may be passed a memory address that doesn't fit in 32 bits...